# Prevent VSCode from scrolling up or down when selecting text

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I use VSCode and select text with a mouse (instead of the trackpad) the view is moving up and down slightly. It is annoying. Usually, it only scrolls when the selection is going off screen. Is there a way to turn this off?

It also moves when I place the cursor on new lines.

Editor settings:

[image]

Comment: You don't have `Editor: Cursor Surrounding Lines` set to something high or an extension that centers the cursor?

Comment: @Mark I've added a screenshot of my settings.

Comment: @Mark I think the problem has to do with the Apple mouse. It is very jerky when selecting or placing text and I think it has to do with single finger mouse scrolling triggering scroll all the time. https://superuser.com/questions/1753991/how-to-scroll-with-two-fingers-on-apple-mouse